# onkeypress event not firing

Tags: jquery, html

I have written a code for work with both mouse and keyboard events. But the `onkeypress` event is not firing in Firefox, IE etc. I have tried with `keydown` event also, but this does not work. The HTML code for the `li` elements are:

```
print "<li class=\"ui-menu-item \" id=\"toli$i\"  value=\"'$name','$email'\" role=\"menuitem\"><a class=\"ui-corner-all\" href=\"#\"  onkeypress=\"keyhandle('$name','$email');\" onclick=\"fillto('toli$i','$name','$email');\">$ename $ediv $email></a></li>";
    }
    elsif($field eq "cc"){

 print "<li class=\"ui-menu-item \" id=\"toli\" role=\"menuitem\"><a class=\"ui-corner-all\" href=\"#\" onkeypress=\"keyhandle('$name','$email');\" onclick=\"fillcc('$name','$email');\">$ename $ediv $email></a></li>";
}
elsif($field eq "bcc"){

 print "<li class=\"ui-menu-item \" id=\"toli\" role=\"menuitem\"><a class=\"ui-corner-all\" href=\"#\" onkeypress=\"keyhandle('$name','$email');\" onclick=\"fillbcc('$name','$email');\">$ename $ediv $email></a></li>";
}
}
print "</ul>";
```

The javascript function is

```
<script language="javascript">
function keyhandle(id,name,email){

alert (id);
 }
</script>
```

The `onclick` event is firing, but `onkeypress` is not firing . Can anyone suggest why this is?

The code which is given to the browser is

```
<div id="displayto" class="display ui-widget"><ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget-content ui-corner-all " style="width: 550px; max-height: 200px;" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" role="listbox"><li class="ui-menu-item " id="toli1" value="'AMAL SMITHA S','amal_smitha@vssc.gov.in'" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" href="#" onkeypress="keyhandle('AMAL SMITHA S','amal_smitha@vssc.gov.in');" onclick="fillto('toli1','AMAL SMITHA S','amal_smitha@vssc.gov.in');">"AMAL SMITHA S" (COM) &lt; amal_smitha@vssc.gov.in&gt;</a></li></ul></div>
```

I have tried the code

```
 $(document).ready(){
        $("#displayto").keypress(function(){
            alert('a');
    });
}
```

But it is also not working. I have given a sequential id to each

item.  I want to pass this sequential id through the keypress function.This id value is used for taking the next id value on "down" arrow press and previous value on up arrow press. If enter key is pressed, the fillto() function is to be called. This code is for the auto completion feature. Is there any other method to do this? Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: I think `onkeypress` is only for text-type inputs, like `type="text"` or `<textarea>`

Comment: @bdares — It isn't. *The onkeypress event occurs when a key is pressed and released over an element. This attribute may be used with most elements.* — http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3

Comment: @Smitha Abhilash — You are generating HTML and JavaScript from Perl and it is the HTML/JavaScript that isn't working. Please show us the code the browser gets, not snippits of the code that generates it.

Comment: Why is this tagged `jQuery` when there is no use of that library in the code you are showing to us?

Comment: What procedure are you using to test your code? How are you focusing the anchors? (Are you even remembering to do so?)

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work for the `a` tag... maybe someone can show me how? http://jsfiddle.net/EY2AL/

Comment: @bdares — You have to take the function out of the mootools onLoad wrapper (your code was scoping it so it wasn't in scope for the attribute (the dependancy on global functions is just one reason why intrinsic event attributes suck)) and you have to give the `<a>` element an `href` attribute so it can be focused. Then just focus the element and press a key. http://jsfiddle.net/EY2AL/1/

Comment: I guess it just doesn't work on chrome.  @Quentin's example works on IE9.

Comment: @bdares — I'm using Chrome and it works for me.

Comment: Your code [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/sE7QC/). Whatever the problem is, it isn't in anything you've put in the question.

Answer (score 6):

This might be a bit too late, but right now I was dealing with this same problem and possibly found a solution.

Mine situation was:

```
<span onclick="javascript: /* some javascript to select element */ " onkeypress="javascript: /* call function to process key event */">...</span>
```

I found somewhere that to enable element to catch key events it needs to be *focusable*. By default all input elements should be focusable and maybe some other ones as well, varying across browsers.

However, you can make an element focusable, in my case I used *tabindex* attribute to achieve this. Like so:

```
<span tabindex="" onclick="javascript: /* some javascript to select element */ " onkeypress="javascript: /* call function to process key event */">...</span>
```

This worked in Firefox, but not in Chrome. Only when I put some value into tabindex attribute, the event was actually fired and javascript in onkeypress="" was executed.

So now I ended up with something like this:

```
<span tabindex="0" onclick="javascript: /* some javascript to select element */ " onkeypress="javascript: /* call function to process key event */">...</span>
```

EDIT:
I forgot to add that you actually need to focus the element. I did that in onclick="" by calling focus().

Comment: Thank you. Well done! Here's my version:<input tabindex="0" type="checkbox" onclick="javascript: $(this).focus()">

Answer (score 0):

Can you use jQuery?? If you can, try something like this, I think could be better:

```
$(document).ready(){
    $("#displayto").keypress(function(){
        alert('a');
    });
}//end of document ready
```

Answer (score 0):

probably the event is loading before the input and that's why is not working, try with the live,

```
$(document).ready(){

        $('input').live('keypress', function (e) {
           if ( e.keyCode == 9 ){
               alert( 'Tab pressed' );
            }else
              alert("another key pressed");
        });
}
```

if you are not using input tags, try with the one that you are using, like id of the div